# Seaborn heatmaps and csv files: 'could not convert string to float' and 'duplicate entries, cannot reshape'

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, heatmap, valueerror

I'm fairly new to Python, so thank you in advance for your patience and understanding. I have looked on Stackoverflow but have not been able to find useful answers. I am using Jupyter Notebook to try and visualize items bought at different stores. For example:

```
Item               Store

Screwdrivers       Walmart
Screws             Home Depot
Potatoes           Trader Joe's
Bleach             Walmart
Napkins            Walmart
Flooring           Home Depot
Treats             Petco
Misc - Item        Trader Joe's
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data = pd.read_csv('OOR_excerpt.csv', encoding='cp1252')
list_string = map(str, data)
df = dfraw[list_string]
sns.heatmap(df)
```

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Misc - Item'

This was working until I logged off for the weekend and came back after clearing cookies and cache. I did not normally need to use the encoding cp1252 code.

1. I have opened and re-saved the csv file on my computer, and reloaded it into Jupyter Notebook (originally I was working with many different columns and just excluding the columns I didn't need, as I should be able to) - and the file is not corrupted in any way that I can tell. Working with only the two columns I need now
2. I have tried adding this, which should convert all these to strings, right? I have made heatmaps before that did not have issues using only alphanumeric values:

   list_string = map(str, cols_to_include)
   df = dfraw[list_string]
3. Using df_heatmap = df.pivot("Item", "Store")
   sns.heatmap(df_heatmap) gives me the error ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Why can't I have duplicate entries?

Comment: Please add some details: What's `dfraw`? How do you want your visualization to look like in the end? `sns.heatmap` expects numbers, so far it's not clear which numbers you would like to draw.

Comment: Dfraw was the raw data before selecting out desired rows; and yes I understand, I only gave an example because I am working with sensitive data.

Answer (score 2):

`sns.heatmap()` function only uses dataframes or series with **numeric** values. Based in your error message, you are using columns that contain **strings** (text).

To create a heatmap only using your numeric columns, use `select_dtype`:

```
data_numeric = data.select_dtype('number')
sns.heatmap(data_numeric)
```

If your columns only contain strings, I am guessing you're attempting to count the unique values and create a heatmap. Try this:

```
columns_of_interest = ['col1', 'col2']
count_table = pd.DataFrame(data[columns of interest].value_counts())
sns.heatmap(count_table)
```

I don't understand your `pivot` issue. I believe it's attempting to duplicate an index, which is not possible because index values is how Pandas references cells.

**Note:** For better guidance, you should always include a small example of how your data looks like (a small table, screenshot, or better explanation); provide an example of what you are trying to achieve; and try to focus your question to one problem.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Heatmap is not really the right kind of visualization for the data I am working with. Do you have any tips on what kind of visualization I could use if I want to show what items are bought from which stores?

Comment: Visualizations rely on some type of numeric values, and since you only have strings, an organized table is the best you can do to represent what items are bought where. You can do this using the `sort` method on your dataframe. Alternatively, you can visualize the count of items each store has, or categorize all items using a new column and then count items for every category and store.